# How does Apache Beam handle multiple windows

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are using Beam 2.2 java sdk with Google Dataflow runner.

We receive batches of 4 hours' data in PubSub (which does not have timestamps) , which we need to throttle and process the resulting windows one by one as each of these require some state information. We can assign timestamps to this data and create windows, but this may result into multiple windows being prepared and emitted at the same time. Does Beam process these windows one by one or we need to explicitly ensure this processing?

Comment: Your use of the word "batch" kind of confuses me here. Normally you want to use [PubsubIO](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io) within a **streaming** dataflow job. My understanding from your description is that  you want to use [User-Specified Timestamps](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io#timestamps-and-record-ids) which is basically a way for you to precisely control how elements read from Pub/Sub will be assigned to windows ([which you define](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing)) in your pipeline. Can you clarify a bit more what is your concern?

Comment: The pipeline will be a streaming pipeline, but it will receive a big chunk of data every 4 hours from PusSub topic. We can create smaller windows using the timestamps, but what I am looking for is the control over execution of these windows - we need them processed sequentially rather than in parallel (albeit at a slower rate).

Comment: You can do what you are looking for using [AfterWatermark](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/triggers#time-based-triggers) triggers. Which logic do you follow when you assign the timestamps? Is your case similar to the one outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing#adding-timestamps-to-a-pcollections-elements)? There's a chance you can also use [stateful processing](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html).